# Pushing an array of objects into Firebase Collection Angular 8

Tags: arrays, angular, firebase, collections, push

I am trying to add a document into an array studyList in my users collection.

So i have a collection users where i have name, etc.. and studyList.

[image]

When i click on a button buy into a DocumentItemComponent i want to add that document into this studyList array.

My code works partially because it adds the document into the array but when i click on another document it changes the first one, it doesn't add another document.

This is my code for the adding function:

```
   addToStudyList(user) {
        const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.id}`);
        const data: UserInterface = {
          studyList: [{
            title: this.document.title,
            language: this.document.language,
            description: this.document.description,
            cover: this.document.cover,
            category: this.document.category,
            field: this.document.field,
            id: this.document.id,
            author: this.document.userUid,
            urlDocument: this.document.urlDocument
          }]

        }
        return userRef.set(data, {merge: true});

   }
```

Can you help me, please?
Thank you! Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you declare:

```
  studyList: [{
            title: this.document.title,
            language: this.document.language,
            description: this.document.description,
            cover: this.document.cover,
            category: this.document.category,
            field: this.document.field,
            id: this.document.id,
            author: this.document.userUid,
            urlDocument: this.document.urlDocument
          }]
```

in this piece of code you are assigning just one object to the the studyList array which overwrites the existing array, instead you should utilize the existing user studyList array and push your new object into it, something like this:

```
  addToStudyList(user) {
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.id}`);
    user.studyList.push({
        title: this.document.title,
        language: this.document.language,
        description: this.document.description,
        cover: this.document.cover,
        category: this.document.category,
        field: this.document.field,
        id: this.document.id,
        author: this.document.userUid,
        urlDocument: this.document.urlDocument
      });
    const data: UserInterface = {
      studyList: user.studyList

    }
    return userRef.update(data);
```

}

Comment: I tried this way @ploofah but now in firebase it is ''studyList: 2''. I think it takes the number of documents.

Comment: I have updated the data object above. This should fix the issue with 2 getting saved. updatedStudyList had the length of the array after pushing.

Comment: yeah sorry.. I just realized the edits won't be visible until moderators approve it. :)
Just use the above line of code.

Comment: It works perfectly!! Thank you so much! I really appreciate it! You're a hero.

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct way to update an array inside a document, but if you are using Firestore, it provides arrayUnion and arrayRemove functions which you can use for adding/removing unique items in the array.

From firestore documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array :

Try this:

```
userRef.update({
  studyList: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(data)
});
```

Comment: Yes i am using firestore and i read the documentation but i don't know exactly how to use this. I'm only injecting firestore in the constructor. Should i import something else? That's the error: DocumentItemComponent.html:62 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'fieldValue' of undefined
    at DocumentItemComponent.addToStudyList

Comment: Whichi library are you using for firebase? Try import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'

Comment: I tried with this but it's not working, i don't know why. Anyway i solved my issue with Nayak's answear, thank you very much!

Comment: I'm the same guy :) Normally I prefer to not send a lot of data over the network everytime, so was trying to see if this works, then you might be able to send only one item, rather than sending all the items everytime you make an add/edit. Anyways, if sending all data works for your case, you are good to go. Thanks!

Comment: Ups, i didn't look at the name! Sorry